# fatal: Access denied for user golden by PAM account configuration [preauth]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, pam

I am trying to setup passwordless ssh from "machineA" to "machineB" but somehow it's not working and I am getting below error. I have already added public key of jenkins user from "machineA" into "authorized_keys" file in "machineB" golden user..

```
jenkins@machineA:~$ ssh golden@machineB
Connection to machineB closed by remote host.
Connection to machineB closed.
```

And I logged into this "machineB" and I checked "auth.log" file and I see below error:

```
Feb 13 14:29:49 machineB sshd[22145]: rexec line 90: Deprecated option RhostsAuthentication
Feb 13 14:29:50 machineB sshd[22145]: pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `golden' from `machineA'
Feb 13 14:29:50 machineB sshd[22145]: fatal: Access denied for user golden by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

And below is how my permission thing is setup on machineB:

```
golden@machineB:~$ ls -lrtha
total 56K
-rw-------  1 golden golden  675 Oct  6 21:39 .profile
-rw-------  1 golden golden 3.6K Oct  6 21:39 .bashrc
-rw-------  1 golden golden  220 Oct  6 21:39 .bash_logout
drwx------  3 golden golden 4.0K Oct  7 12:03 .config
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root     4.0K Oct 19 18:41 ..
-rw-------  1 golden golden  12K Feb 13 13:54 .bash_history
-rw-------  1 golden golden  11K Feb 13 14:10 .viminfo
drwx------  2 golden golden 4.0K Feb 13 14:10 .ssh
drwx------  4 golden golden 4.0K Feb 13 14:10 .

golden@machineB:~$ ls -lrtha .ssh/
total 24K
-rw------- 1 golden golden 1.7K Oct 19 22:46 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 golden golden  381 Oct 19 22:46 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 golden golden 2.2K Oct 19 22:48 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 golden golden 1.2K Feb 13 14:10 authorized_keys
drwx------ 4 golden golden 4.0K Feb 13 14:10 ..
drwx------ 2 golden golden 4.0K Feb 13 14:10 .
```

And this is my `/etc/security/access.conf` file on machineB:

```
+:ALL:LOCAL
+:root:ALL
+:tom:ALL
# generated by puppet
# beginldap
+:@golden:ALL
+:@opers:ALL
+:@unixcore:ALL
+:stack:ALL
+:comet:ALL
# endldap
-:ALL:ALL
```

I am using below permission:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Did you see this? -- https://serverfault.com/questions/540004/ssh-access-denied-by-pam-account-configuration-for-one-non-root-user-but-not/540008